# How can I close a window with javascript using setTimeout?

Tags: vaadin7

onclick of a button creates a window, add to UI, I want  to close this window using javascript ?  please advice how to close this window  using javascript after some timeout?

```
Button  button= new Button("load Content",e->{
        Window  sub= new Window();
        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(sub);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);
```

// here 5000 ms refers to 5 seconds